# Showing $A_n$ is maximal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $$A_n \leq A_nC_{S_n}(\sigma) \leq S_n$$ for some $\sigma \in S_n$.

I would like to argue that $A_nC_{S_n}$ is either $A_n$ or $S_n$.

I have so far as to think if $A_nC_{S_n}$ contains an odd cycle, it generates $S_n$ but it is still somewhat incomplete.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $S_n$ has order $n!$, and $A_n$ has order $n!/2$.  What can you say about the order of the group lying between them?

Comment: Ah I see. Using the Lagrange's theorem, the order of any subgroup must divide $n!$ and it cannot be bigger than the order of $A_n$ while being less than the order of $S_n$. Thanks! @RaviFernando

Comment: @HenriL, feel free to answer your own question if you have found it, will also push it out of unanswered queue!